# Writing Data to Azure EventHub Connection timed out Issue

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I've written a piece of Java code to send some dummy data to Azure EventHub, when i try executing the code, getting the below message, from my initial observation it looks like trying to establish a connection to eventHub and failing after some milliseconds. Is there any firewall to be allowed or is it something which i'm missing that needs to be taken care. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error message:

21824 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler  - onTransportError: hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net:5671], error[Connection timed out: no further information]
21824 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory  - onConnectionError: messagingFactory[MessagingFactoryf90a75], hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net], error[Connection timed out: no further information]
21824 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory  - onConnectionError: messagingFactory[MessagingFactoryf90a75], hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net], open hasn't complete, stopping the reactor
21828 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ConnectionHandler  - onTransportClosed: hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net:5671], error[Connection timed out: no further information]
21828 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory  - onConnectionError: messagingFactory[MessagingFactoryf90a75], hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net], error[Connection timed out: no further information]
Exception in thread "main" 21828 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory  - onConnectionError: messagingFactory[MessagingFactoryf90a75], hostname[CTDATA.servicebus.windows.net], closing current connection

Comment: Are you following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send#send-events)?

Comment: Hello @IvanYang, Yes, i followed the same doc. Still no luck.